# Dynamic property to a C# object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am thinking designing a field in db that stores the Serialized Object. When I call that property in entity, that returns String property which is obvious. I am looking for a way to attach a property dynamically and assign the deserialized object to the Class instance. Can any one suggest the best possible way?

## DB Structure

### Users Table

UserId 
 .....
 .....
 ..... 
 UserNotes (nvarchar)

## Class Structure

```
  [Serializable]
 [XmlRoot("Notes")]
 public class GenericNotes {
     public DateTime Date {
         get;
         set;
     }
     public String CommentBy {
         get;
         set;
     }
     public string Type {
         get;
         set;
     }
     public string Comment {
         get;
         set;
     }
 }
 public class Users {
     public UserId int {
         get;
         set;
     }
     public string UserNotes {
         get;
         set;
     }
     // I dont have the following definition in the class because its coming from entity framework. 
     //But I want the following property attached to the class on runtime. 
     //I will take care of of deserializing using extension methods or some sort methods.
     public string List < GenericNotes > NotesCollection {
         get;
         set;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you want to create a `Notes` table with a foreign key relationship to the `Users` table?

Comment: The de-serialize method only looks at the xml data and doesn't care if there are extra properties in the class structure.  Making a property private the serialize method won't output these properties in the xml output.

Comment: Consider using [DataContract] and [DataMember] instead of Xml serialization. DataContractSerailizer still uses XML as the format, but allows you to opt-in instead of requiring that you opt-out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of property you can have extension method to do this

```
public static class UserExtension
{
    public static List<GenericNotes> GetNotes(this Users users)
    {
        //return your deserialized GenericNotes from string 
    }
}
```

Then you can use this anywhere like

```
 List<GenericNotes> notes = users.GetNotes();
```